# Prevent Entity Framework DataFirst Timeout from being over ridden when model is updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have a db model that while I've been developing I have to update frequently at times...

I have the following in the initializer:

```
    public OrthrusDbEntities()
        : base("name=OrthrusDbEntities")
    {
        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 180; // value in seconds
    }
```

This works great, but everytime I update the model it gets over ridden.  I know how to add DataAnnotations to my model using another partial class, so I'm wondering if there is a way to add this line to a partial class for the initializer too... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how you fix this... outside of anything to do with the edmx (obviously not inside your MyDb.Context.cs):

```
public partial class MyDbEntities : DbContext 
{
    public MyDbEntities (string ConnectionString)
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {
        this.SetCommandTimeOut(360);
    }

    public void SetCommandTimeOut(int Timeout)
    {
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
    }
}
```